# Which pronoun to use to refer to a city?

Tags: word-usage

"Have you ever been to Paris?" "Yes, and I liked it."

How would the latter sentence be translated to german? My attempt:

> Ja, und ich habe sie gemocht.

Or

> Ja, und sie hat mir gefallen.

I'm using "sie" because it's "die Stadt". However I've never found any of those forms in actual german texts. It might just be a coincidence of course, but I'm wondering whether they are correct.

Comment: [**das** Paris](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Paris).

Comment: "Paris" kann nicht mit "Stadt" übersetzt werden. "Der Ort", "die Lokalität", "das Gebiet" - es gibt keine Geschlechtskonstanz in der Generalisierung oder Spezialisierung.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*"Ja, und ich habe sie gemocht."* is wrong*, unless the word 'Stadt' actually appears in the question:

> Warst du schon einmal in der beliebten Stadt Paris?
>   Ja, und sie hat mir gefallen.

Apart from that, I would use the following reply to *"Warst du schon einmal in Paris?"*:

> Ja, und ich habe es [dort] genossen

*"Es"* refers to the event of being there / the time which was spent there.

You could also say:

> Ja, und es hat mir [dort] gefallen.

If you want to set the focus on the city, use the following sentence:

> Ja, und die Stadt hat mir gefallen.

---

*) You might consider using 'sie' (for referring to a city, e.g. *Paris*) a personification of the city. It is therefore not wrong in all contexts, but you rather encounter such phrases in poetic texts than in everyday language.

Comment: 'Ich habe sie gemocht' is definitely not _always_ wrong. It's weird, I give you that. But if you fancy yourself a bit on the poetic side, you might as well say you liked her, implying that Paris is like a woman (beautiful, sensuous etc. if you catch my drift). That works just as well in german as it does in english, _especially_ for Paris :)

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla: I agree, but that would be in the same terroritory as a statement like "Ich habe **Gisela** getroffen und mit **ihm** gesprochen.", to (humorously, for example) express that you recognize a number of rather masculine traits in a woman named Gisela. Makes sense in context and with poetic license in mind, but I doubt that is what the OP was looking for here.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla As O. R. Mapper said, you can always personify objects. While personification is a canonical stylistic device, I don't think you use it in everyday language (especially not as a beginner). Nevertheless, I updated my answer to reflect your comment :)

Answer (score 7):

Definitely "es", as all cities are neutral, even when the name is a compound ending in -burg , -berg, etc. (**das** Hamburg, **das** Heidelberg)

To give a few more examples:

```
Das Hamburg, aus dem Benedikt die Flucht ins Jenseits antrat, war eine Art hoffnungsloser   
Vorposten im wilden Wikinger-Land. [Die Zeit, 07.07.2005]

Das Frankfurt der Jahreswende 1828 / 29, wo sich dies alles zuträgt, ist dabei kein 
austauschbarer fiktionaler Ort. [Frankfurter Rundschau, 02.01.1998, S. 22]
```

Comment: It shoul dbe added that the article is normally not used, only as in these examples when we don't speak of the city itself / as a whole / as geographic entity, but rather about a historical aspect of the city. But the genus is also visible when using attributes ("O, du mein geliebtes Hamburg")

Comment: I don't think it has to be the historical aspect of the city, strictly speaking. I can think of a few more examples where the article is justified: das Rom von heute; das Wien, wie ich es kenne; das Hamburg der Obdachlosen; das "schöne" Paris, das Paris der Postkarten; ... It is true, though, that an article is not usually needed when simply referring to the city as such.